# meaning of the phrase "telling effect"

Tags: meaning

It is from a [BBC sports article.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/boxing/43608618) Here is the excerpt:

> The Briton, 28, used his left hand to **telling effect** throughout an intriguing affair, in which New Zealand's Parker displayed swift hands, movement and impressive durability.

What does **telling effect** mean there, and why was an article omitted before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Effect](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Effect) can be a noun or a verb. I can have a "strong effect" on something or I can "effect a change". It can also be replaced by "result" in this context.

[Telling](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/telling) means:

> Having force or producing a striking effect
>
> Revealing previously unknown information

So the Briton was (possibly) previously unknown for his left handed abilities but he used them to achieve a striking result.

Comment: Telling can also mean to have a strong or significant effect. In this context I don't think it means that Anthony Joshua was previously unkown for his left handed punches. Rather it means his left handed punches did significant damage to Parker his opponent.

Comment: @Sarriesfan You’re right! It was the first definition, too. I’ve edited to correct.

Comment: Why was an article left out before the phrase "telling effect"?

Comment: The dictionary entries suggest this is normal for "effect" - you can use “to good effect”. There are other words like this such as "applause", "skill", "impact" that are used in prepositional phrases without articles.

Answer (score 0):

telling effect means "effective" or "striking", that causes a particular reaction as intended. If I say something offensive to somebody and it has a telling effect then it means it is very striking.